# Dismiss single custom notification

Tags: android

There is a tutorial on Android Developer website which guides you on how to create a custom notification.It works great on most of the android devices however some branded phone of motorola (Motorola Electrify) have their own dismiss button.I guess that this firmware/ROM of android overrides the default XML layout of the default notification. thus, a custom notification does not have this dismiss button.

[image]

Is there an easy way to keep this button? or the only way is to check whether that this device have such a button and if so add one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to keep this button?

By definition, no, since you did not put the button there in the first place.

> or the only way is to check whether that this device have such a button

I have no idea how you would do that.

> and if so add one?

I have no idea how you would do that either. For devices that lack per-`Notification` dismiss options (Android 1.x/2.x), you cannot have a button of your own. You can always have your `Notification` be set for auto-cancel (e.g., `setAutoCancel(true)` with `Notification.Builder`), in which case tapping anywhere on the `Notification` will dismiss it.

Comment: well, dismissing the notification is not what I'm actually looking for. I need it to act as a normal notification just with this dismiss button in case the ROM has one.

Comment: @kirill: You have no control over whether the OS puts a dismiss button there (other than to not use `setOngoingEvent()`, which should always exclude such buttons).